# Exporting Polygons (RGB color bands) nto CSV

Tags: polygon, csv, google-earth-engine

I have drawn ~40 polygons over NAIP imagery to collect their R, G, B color bands. I now want to export each polygon with its associated RGB color values into a CSV file so I can plot the polygons against one another and compare them. I have attatched a screenshot of my geometry polygons and their color bands.

[[Inspector tab shows associated R, G, B color values with individual drawn polygons][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA3GX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA3GX.png)

Comment: Please include the code into the question and a link to your script (which includes the polygons). This way it is easier for anyone trying to help you, so they don't have to type code from your screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of the values using reduceRegion (or reduceRegions if you have multiple geometries) and the ee.Reducer.toList() reducer (or the toCollection reducer if you want to export a table).